Python Pandas Removing Row based on some filter rules

so, i have csv files like image above, which i want create filter :
if 'Bids' < 3 AND 'Price' > 149
then data should be deleted, like the image above, data number 2 should be deleted
i already try this approach but didnt get what i want,

def filter(csv_file, csv2_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=0, index_col=False)

    #Convert 'Bid' and 'Price' columns to numeric type
    df['Bids'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Bids'], errors='coerce')
    df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'], errors='coerce')
    
    # Apply filtering conditions
    filtered_df = df[(df['Bids'] < 3) & (df['Price'] > 149)]

    filtered_df.to_csv(csv2_file, index=False)


as the result, the new output csv file is removing all the data,

please review my code

You should debug yourself, what is the output of pd.to_numeric(df['Price'], errors='coerce')?

0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
Name: Price, dtype: float64, all NaN @mozway

So what is your conclusion about to_numeric?
